# Ubuntu 18.10 freshly updated freezes everytime at shutdown?

Tags: updates, shutdown, reboot, 18.10

I’ve just updated from 18.04 to 18.10 and whenever I do Power Off, the system freezes and won’t shutdown.

I have no clue to what I should do and I tried a few things which solved for the same problem in older versions - but - no clue for me.

Comment: When it appears to freeze, try hitting the ESC key, and you should see a text screen. Look for FAIL messages, or note what the LAST item that is displayed. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema , i rebooted and tryied to hit the ESC key but nothing occured.

Comment: In `terminal`, type `sudo shutdown -h now` and watch for errors or freezes.

Comment: I typed `sudo shutdown -h now ` and the screen freezes and no error messages appeared. Even pressing the ESC key.  @heynnema

Comment: In `terminal`, type `reboot` and see if that works.

Comment: `reboot` have not worked :(, freezes the same way

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if you can shutdown or reboot from there. Do you know how to check /var/log/syslog, and dmesg, and journalctl?